# Subsonic 2.2 and EnterpriseLibrary 4.1 in Framework 2.0

Tags: asp.net, subsonic, frameworks, enterprise-library

Hi i use subsonic version 2.2 in my project and this version of subsonic use EnterpriseLibrary 4.1

but i use EnterpriseLibrary 3.1 because i use framework 2.0, the version 4.1 need framework 3.5 or later, the problem is when i use subsonic in the web config i have this

and when is load fail, and showme this

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

How i can solve this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Subsonic 2.2 only supports C# 3.0.  Use a prior version of subsonic.